# Using CALL command with an IF condition in batch

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements, call

I'm trying to set up a code with passwords, where a different password will take you to a different directory. All the directories are in the same .bat file, but i want to use another .bat to call the passwords and take me to the directory. I'm not sure how to do it, and am finding it difficult to locate in the topic searches.

My code looks like this:

```
@echo off
:takemeto
cls
echo Enter Password
set /p name=
call C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Batch files\passwords.bat

:password1
cls
echo You have chosen Password 1

:password2
cls
echo You have chosen Password 2
```

The CALL is meant to locate and use my file with the passwords. the files has the passwords and the directories, which looks like this:

```
:Passwords
if "%name%" == "password1" goto password1
if "%name%" == "password2" goto password2
/end
```

Hope this is clear,
Thanks-Rob

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Are you getting an error? _You realize those passwords will be stored in plain text_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your external batch script echo its output.  Capture it with a `for /f` loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set extbat=C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Batch files\passwords.bat

:takemeto
cls
set /p name="Enter Password: "
for /f %%I in ('"%extbat%" %name%') do goto %%I

:invalid
echo Invalid password entered.
set name=
pause
goto takemeto

:password1
cls
echo You have chosen Password 1
goto :EOF

:password2
cls
echo You have chosen Password 2
goto :EOF
```

example `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Batch files\passwords.bat`:

```
@echo off
if #%1==# (
    echo takemeto
) else if #%1==#correct1 (
    echo password1
) else if #%1==#correct2 (
    echo password2
) else echo invalid
```

... where `correct1` and `correct2` are the passwords you expect your user to enter.